# Regex match in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm having kind of trouble match all the url that has the same format like this : `planning|test/test` and if so, to store in LocalStorage.
Here's my code :

```
if( window.location.href.split('#')[1].match('/planning\|[a-z]*\/[a-z]*/'))
{
    localStorage.setItem('hash_tag', window.location.href.split('#')[1]);
}
```

The issue here is the regex `match` doesn't quite do the job here. Any help with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `window.location.href.split('#')[1]` you could just use `location.hash`

Comment: Can you give a few examples of *should match* - *shouldn't match*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "'" (apostrophes) symbols for regex pattern in match. Try to run the following 2 samples in your browser's console (I checked in FF 39):

```
// prints 'MATCH'
var to_match = 'planning|test/test';
if (to_match.match(/planning\|[a-z]*\/[a-z]*/)) {
    console.log('MATCH');
} else {
    console.log('WAT');
}

// prints 'WAT'
var to_match = 'planning|test/test';
if (to_match.match('/planning\|[a-z]*\/[a-z]*/')) {
    console.log('MATCH');
} else {
    console.log('WAT');
}
```

Also, you may use https://regex101.com/#javascript to test your regexes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your regex is that you declared it with `'...'`. You need to remove `'` around the regex string literal.

In case the strings can have *both* `planning` **OR** `[a-z]*/[a-z]*`, you can use

```
if( window.location.href.split('#')[1].match(/planning|[a-z]*\/[a-z]*/)) {
      localStorage.setItem('hash_tag', window.location.href.split('#')[1]);
}
```

or

```
if( /planning|[a-z]*\/[a-z]*/.test(window.location.href.split('#')[1])) {
      localStorage.setItem('hash_tag', window.location.href.split('#')[1]);
}
```

Note that `\|` matches a literal `|` symbol and does not denote alternation.

If you want to match `|` as a literal, just use

```
if( /planning\|[a-z]*\/[a-z]*/.test(window.location.href.split('#')[1])) {
      localStorage.setItem('hash_tag', window.location.href.split('#')[1]);
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can replace `window.location.href.split('#')[1]` with `location.hash.substring(1)` since `location.hash` returns the anchor part of the URL, including the hash sign (#).

Comment: It kinda work now, but it matches everything that start with `planning|`, and i don't wanna match url like `planning|654656` !

Comment: So, `|` is a literal? Then keep the escaped `\|` as in your original regex. Then main issue is with apostrophes round the regex.